# Resolution 1024x611, why is it not 1024x600? (Or why does SM_CYFULLSCREEN report a slightly too large height=)

Tags: winapi, resolution

I am posting here on the off-chance that someone knows why my screen size is reported as 611 instead of 600?

```
GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYFULLSCREEN)
```

returns 611. My netbook is 1024x600, so I expected 600, not 611.

Googling for 1024x611 turns up a surprising number of results, also.

Comment: Maybe some details of what system you're running might help. Is this a netbook/tablet?

Comment: @CrazyCasta, yes, a netbook, an ASUS.

Comment: Linked: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4631292/how-detect-current-screen-resolution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from other forum threads, it seems that `GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYFULLSCREEN)` does not always return the exptected result. it seems to be adjusted, and may not be the value you want.

try using `GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN)`, which will return the size of your primary monitor.

*(also, note that some people use multiple monitors: take care of not constraining your application to a single monitor)*

Comment: This was it. Would be very interesting to know the reason why CYFULLSCREEN mangles this number, but I am happy enough that it works now. :-)

Comment: i do think it just represents something else: i am not sure, but it may be the height needed for a window when you want to make the _client area_ full screen (although i don't have anything to back this down).

Answer (score 1):

[SM_CXFULLSCREEN and SM_CYFULLSCREEN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724385%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) returns the size of a full screen window, so would usually be less than your screen size due to the taskbar:

> The width of the client area for a full-screen window on the primary
>   display monitor, in pixels. To get the coordinates of the portion of
>   the screen that is not obscured by the system taskbar or by
>   application desktop toolbars, call the SystemParametersInfo function
>   with the SPI_GETWORKAREA value.

Compare it to what [SPI_GETWORKAREA in SystemParametersInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724947%28v=vs.85%29#Desktop) returns for your display? Or what is your display set to in the control panel??

A 1024x640 screen would be a true 16:10 ratio and would amount to ~ 611 y available desktop size.