# Get window handle of SDL 2 application

Tags: c, winapi, sdl, sdl-2

I would like to get the handle of a SDL2 window, to use it with WinApi.

I retrieve that handle with the following code :

```
/* All the SDL initalisation... */
SDL_Window* window = SDL_CreateWindow("My Window", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
                        SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, RESX, RESY, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
SDL_Renderer* renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED);
if (window == NULL || renderer == NULL) {
    MessageBox(NULL, L"SDL initialisation error", NULL, MB_OK);
    exit(-1);
}

SDL_SysWMinfo wmInfo;
SDL_GetWindowWMInfo(window, &wmInfo);
HWND hwnd = wmInfo.info.win.window;
```

But at this point, `hwnd` adress is `0xcccccccc` (unused).

Did I do something wrong?

Comment: Add `SDL_VERSION(&wmInfo.version);` before calling `SDL_GetWindowWMInfo`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[SDL Wiki page](http://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_GetWindowWMInfo) in remarks section says that `info.version` must be initialised before usage. Code example suggests using `SDL_VERSION(&info.version);` before querying WM info.

```
SDL_SysWMinfo wmInfo;
SDL_VERSION(&wmInfo.version);
SDL_GetWindowWMInfo(window, &wmInfo);
HWND hwnd = wmInfo.info.win.window;
```