# Windowed fullscreen

Tags: c++, winapi

Using win32 I create a window like this:

```
RECT windowRect = {0, 0, width, height};
AdjustWindowRectEx(&windowRect, WS_OVERLAPPED | WS_CAPTION | WS_THICKFRAME, FALSE, WS_EX_APPWINDOW);
mWindowHandle = CreateWindow(wcex.lpszClassName, wcex.lpszClassName, WS_OVERLAPPED | WS_CAPTION | WS_THICKFRAME,
                             CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, windowRect.right - windowRect.left, windowRect.bottom - windowRect.top,
                             nullptr, nullptr, mInstanceHandle, nullptr);
```

For example, right now I have 1920x1080 max, if I pass those values the client area will have 1920x1080, but the overall window size will be too large, dissapearing off-screen.

`width` and `height` are arbitary values passed to the function. The effect I want to achieve is that if it is set to the maximum (or above) the resolution of the screen, the whole window will be clamped to fit the screen.

Is there an easy way to do this in win32?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4631292/how-detect-current-screen-resolution

Comment: [`AdjustWindowRectEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632667.aspx): *"Note that you cannot specify the **WS_OVERLAPPED** style."*

Comment: The linked question dosn't deal with client-space though?

Comment: Use `MonitorFromRect` and `GetMonitorInfo` to discover the monitor's workspace area, and clip your rectangle to that before opening the window.