# How to get combined size of multiple monitors C++

Tags: c++, mfc

We have just provided support in our latest game for multiple dialogs across multiple monitors. We store the position of each dialog so that it can reopened as the user last left it. But if the user turns off one monitor and launches our game then the dialogs will be opened off screen. I want to write some code in C++ to determine of the stored position is within the bounds of the combined screens and if not then to change it so it is.

How do I find the current list of monitors?

How do I get the size of these?

Thanks.

Comment: This StackOverflow question should address your needs: [How detect current screen resolution?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4631292/how-detect-current-screen-resolution)