# How do I get the resolution of a window in C++?

Tags: c++, winapi, resolution, gdi

```
#include <windows.h>

int main()
{
    HDC Window = GetWindowDC(FindWindow(NULL,"Window Example Title"));


    return 0;
}
```

How could I get the resolution of a window, such as this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How detect current screen resolution?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4631292/how-detect-current-screen-resolution)

Comment: "Resolution" doesn't mean much of anything.  Don't lose the return value of FindWindow() and you can call GetWindowRect() to get the window *size*.

Comment: That question was the top google result for "resolution window api" - please try to do a little research first.

Comment: You need to define what you mean by "resolution".

Comment: @MartinBonner On the other hand, it seems like the question is asking about a window property rather than a screen property. So it seems pretty unlikely that your Google search is going to be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably you mean the available graphics area, which in Windows is called the **client area**.

You can use the [`GetClientRect`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633503(v=vs.85).aspx) function to find its current size.

There is a corresponding [`GetWindowRect`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633519(v=vs.85).aspx) for the window itself.